# What happens when I call a function with an array name as an argument?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I am reading the TCPL by K&R, when I read something about array and pointer, I write this small code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sum(int a[])
{
    int t = 0;
    int length = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]) ;
//  printf("%d\n",length);
    for(int i = 0; i != length; ++i)
    {
        t += a[i];
    }
    return t;
}
int main()
{
    int b[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    printf("%d\n",sum(b));
    return 0;
}
```

The output answer is 1 NOT 15, then I debug this code by adding `printf("%d\n",length);` the  output length is 1 NOT 5. 
The TCPL tells that a array name converts to pointer when the array name used as argument, but the output answer is wrong, so I wonder that:

1. What happend when call a funcion with array name used as argument?
2. The array `a[]` used parameter in `sum(int a[])` has storage or not?
3. I see two styles when calling a array : `fun(int a[]); fun(b)` and `fun(int *a);fun(b)`,what the difference?

Thx very much :-)

Comment: This gets asked roughly 3-4 times a day.

Comment: `int length = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]) ;` sizeof(a) is 4 bytes, sizeof(a[0]) is 4 bytes as well. How about using length()?

Comment: plus, your `for` isn't correct. it should be `for (int i = 0; i <= length; ++i){...}`

Comment: @Sergio: There's no `length()` in C.

Comment: @varnie: No, if length were 5, your loop accessed a non-existing element a[5]. Undefined behavior.

Comment: @Jens was a long time ago, forgot c :), but guess there is some sort of

Comment: @varnie concur with Jens. Your loop termination condition will reach beyond the end of the array and into undefined behavior. There is nothing wrong with the OP's for-loop. His length calculation is wrong; the usage of the length calculation in the for-loop, however, is correct.

Comment: @Sergio: No, there isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third question gets to the heart of the matter: there is no difference between those two as far as the compiler is concerned.  Everything about how the argument is passed is the same.

Therefore, in response to your second question, the `a` parameter doesn't have storage for the underlying array, nor are the members of that array copied.  The only storage allocated is for an `int *` pointer, and that pointer is stored in `a`.  (That somewhat answers your first question as well.)

So, in your function:

```
int length = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]) ;
```

is equivalent to

```
int length = sizeof(int *) / sizeof(int);
```

which returns 1 on systems where pointers and ints are the same size.  If you run this on 64-bit Linux, you will get 2 instead, since pointers are 64 bits and ints are 32 bits.

Comment: If I add  'int length = sizeof(b) / sizeof(b[0]) ;'  and return  the right answer:5.  Two different usage of 'sizeof'??

Comment: In `main`?  Yes, because `b` in `main` is declared as an array and has a size.  It's only as a function parameter that arrays "decay" to pointers and lose their size information.  The `sizeof` calculation works for arrays declared as local or global variables rather than parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot call a function and pass a whole array; if you use an array name as a function argument, it is implicitly rewritten as ("decays to") a pointer to its first element. It is equivalent to writing

```
 int sum(int *a) { ... }
```

Thus, within the function, `sizeof array`, does NOT give you the size of the array, only the size of a pointer to its first element.

So how do you know how many elements there are in the array? You need to pass this number explicitly to functions (or define a macro with the number of elements and use it where needed).

Answer (score 1):

Calling `sizeof` on an array declared as follows

```
 int a[5];
```

will return the size of the array how you currently think it will (ie the full size in bytes of the array - in this case 20 bytes on my machine). When you pass an array like this to a function, the array will decay to a pointer to its first element. Thus when you call `sizeof` on your function argument you are actually calling it on a **pointer** type. Had you declared your function to take an `int *` argument, the error would be more obvious as the type of the variable that you call `sizeof` is explicit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your call, and there is no difference between `fun(int a[])` and `fun(int *a)` (expect that it is more obvious to the reader that you expect an array and not any pointer). Bot arguments are a pointer to an int.

Your problem here is how you try to determine the length of the array. As the square brackets are empty, there is no way for the compiler to know how long the array behind `a` is. You can for example provide the length of the array as a second argument. Note: When calling the function, `sizeof(b)` will provide the correct length, because the compiler knows its length.

Answer (score -1):

The `sizeof()` operator can not be used for getting a dynamically allocated array length.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) you can find examples of the `sizeof()` using.

When you try to do `sizeof(array_ptr)` it is actually **gives you size of the pointer**.

Thus, **you have to pass array length as parameter of the function**

Comment: -1, your first setence is just wrong.

Comment: Still not completely correct, VLA are allocated dynamically, too. What C sees as arrays, will always work with `sizeof`. The thing is just that in the function you get a pointer and not an array.